# Unable to edit tables in SQL Server 2008 database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am creating an application in c# which requires me to embed a database, I added a new `Service based Database` . I added it to the application, I created a table via the `designer` and added data to it. Here I started facing problems. I am able to add new records but unable to edit any rows. I noted a weird behavior.

[image]

- When the rows are just 1 or 2, I am able to edit them without any
  issues.

[image]

- But when the number of rows becomes more , say 5 of 7, I am not able
  to edit any rows,

I am getting an error

> The row values updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or
>   they alter multiple rows

[image]

I have neither mentioned a unique constraint nor a not null constraint. All the columns are of data type `text`. I am not sure what causes this problem. Can somebody explain me whats goin on??

PS: and sometimes,I also get an error as seen in Screenshot 2. For such cases,when I click on `Execute SQL` , then the data is getting inserted.

---

```
***After using an Identity column, the issue is solved. Thanks a lot guys :)
```

Now another issue is coming up, I am able to edit in the designer but I also have a dataGridView binded to the database and I am not able to edit(update) values in it, any suggestions??
This is the code, I am using

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                this.Validate();
                this.core3BindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.core3TableAdapter.Update(this.coreDataSet.Core3);
        }***
```

Comment: Side-note: you should **avoid** using `text`, `ntext` and `image` - [those datatypes have been deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) - use `(n)varchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` instead

Comment: does your table have a primary key field set? Can you add your table definition to the question?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solutions and comments guys,the issue is solved in designer view, but I still face the same problem in dataGridView which is binded to the same database. I am unable to edit(update). Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Niranjan you add primary key on your table in order to don't create integrity problem.

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
   Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   .......
);
```

I suggest you identity treatment, but you can adjust your primary key, it's just additional suggestion

Comment: Yes you were right, adding an identity solved the issue in designer view, but I still face the same problem in dataGridView which is binded to the same database. I am unable to edit(update). Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Using this you can avoid duplicate data

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable 
( 
   Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
     ....... 
);
```

Create Id column with primary key

IDENTITY(1,1) property automatically increament your ID column value for each row.